# Assigning a perspective for each project on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit, subversive, perspective

I'm using SVN (Subversive) for some projects and git (EGit) for others, so I've configured two different perspectives for each type of project. I'd like to know if there's a way to associate a perspective for each project, so that when I open them the perspective is changed automatically.

Is there a way, native or via a plugin, to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, it is very hard, if not impossible to do this. At project creation sometimes a perspective change is triggered (e.g. the creation of a plug-in project opens the PDE view). Otherwise, no general perspective opening method is used.

If you write your own plug-in, it could provide the required switch: either by listening to the opening of the project, or by adding a different Open project command, it is possible to write code that changes the current perspective. On the other hand, I don't know any of those plug-ins available.